# How to open emulators in different windows at Android Studio (Bumblebee | 2021.1.1)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have two running emulators but they open together in different tabs and in one single window.

How to open them in two different window?

[image]

[image]

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-96-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: JUnit4-Parallel-Runner (1.5), com.intellij.javafx (1.0.3), com.intellij.marketplace (211.7628.36), com.atlassian.bitbucket.references (2021.1.195), com.thoughtworks.gauge (211.6693.111), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.4)
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

File->Settings->Tools->Emulator, and uncheck Launch in a tool window
Then they will open in their own stand alone windows again.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is there any advantage of using emulator in a tool window over standalone windows?

Answer (score 23):

For **Mac OS** you can navigate as follow.

> Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator and deselect Launch in a tool window.

Official Ref : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio

Comment: I had to restart AS to make this setting work.

Comment: @Rohan No need to restart AS, just kill & restart the Emulator.

Comment: @DarShan is correct, just close the current open emulators and run/build again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

call them from terminal and they'll be separate entities entirely. do something like `/your_android_sdk/bin/emulator @emulator_name -no-snapshot-load &>/dev/null &`

[image]

Comment: It works!


```cd C:\Users\***user_name***\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools```

```emulator.exe -avd Pixel_3_API_26```