# How open the emulator on Android studio with the old way ? (Before bumblebee)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ide

In bumblebee version of android studio the emulator is display like in the screen. I cannot move it on an other screen of something like that.

In the old way the emulator was detached from the ide.

How can I get the view of the old way with bumblebee version ?

[image]

EDIT :
I don't have access to "View Mode" when clicking on three Dots

[image]

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70923615/11582192

Comment: @Per.J Technically that's not "the old way" as it's still tied to AS. It's just in a separate "tool window" instead of on it's own like it used to be

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To run the emulator in a separate window

**Windows OS (Answered by [Per.J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11582192/per-j): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70923615/3057112)**

> File > Settings > Tools > Emulator and deselect Launch in a tool window.

**Mac OS**

> Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator and deselect Launch in a tool window.

Official Ref : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio

Answer (score -1):

File > Settings > Tools > Emulator and deselect Launch in a tool window.

**For Windows**

Comment: This answer already exist.