# Open the Emulator in a different window after Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) update

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

The emulator is built-in the Android Studio UI by default after updating to the `Bumblebee (2021.1.1)` version.
As shown in bellow image there are 5 options in view mode for changing it.

[image]

I tried all but any of them doesn't show emulator stand alone like older versions.

I want to see emulator like this without any window:

[image]

How can I achieve this behavior like in the older versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open emulators in different windows at Android Studio (Bumblebee | 2021.1.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923189/how-to-open-emulators-in-different-windows-at-android-studio-bumblebee-2021-1)

Comment: No, It doesn't.

Comment: so why did you accept my answer? it's the exact same answer

Comment: Because it solved my problem.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923189/how-to-open-emulators-in-different-windows-at-android-studio-bumblebee-2021-1 this should solve your problem too

Comment: Two different questions may have same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator ->** Uncheck **`Launch in a tool window`**, Click **`ok`**.
For me, restarting the IDE was required too.

Answer (score 0):

View Mode > Window
**Does Work**
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DakgO.png)

Comment: emulator is shown inside a window, I don't want see window.